# How to use MySQL to extract first few rows from all tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, extract

I know how to query out the first few rows of a table at a time in mysql. But I have a database with more than 50 tables so the task becomes tedious. I wonder if there's a way to retrieve them all at once?

I know that in sql server we could use this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 3 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
  FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sql);
```

But I don't know how to do it with mySQL.

Thank you!

Comment: There may be compelling reasons for having 50 tables in a database, but it can be symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Does OS have xargs (Unix-like)?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM [tbl] LIMIT 3`. While the SQL standard is free to choose any 3 rows, the first 3 rows is the usual implementation on a single table select.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM schema_id.name LIMIT 3
```

Assuming, **schema_id** is your schema name and **name** is your table name.
It returns first 3 rows.

Based on the condition, you can opt for MAX() or other aggregate function to make it return specific rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course not a MySQL-only answer, but since I recently needed to accomplish what OP wants, and I don't see another answer, here's *a* solution.

```
mysql [args] -s -e "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='[your_db]'" | xargs -I{} mysql [args] -e "USE [your_db]; SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 3"
```

Where `[args]` are the arguments used for the MySQL command line (host and port and such), and `[your_db]` is the name of the DB you want to dump.